# Fast python XML validator with XPath support

Tags: python, xml, validation, xpath, xsd

I need to read a large XML (65 Mb), validate it against a xsd, and run XPath queries on it. Below, I've given an lxml version of that. It takes a lot of time (over 5 minutes) to run the query but validation seems to be pretty quick.

I've a couple of questions. How would a performance minded Python programmer write the program using lxml? Secondly, if lxml is not the right thing for the job, what else? and could you please give a code snippet?

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from lxml import etree

start = datetime.now()
schema_file = open("library.xsd")
schema = etree.XMLSchema(file=schema_file)
parser = etree.XMLParser(schema = schema)
data_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
tree = etree.parse(data_file, parser)
root = tree.getroot()
data_file.close()
schema_file.close()
end = datetime.now()
delta = end-start
print "Parsing time = ", delta

start = datetime.now()
name_list = root.xpath("book/author/name/text()")
print ("Size of list = " + str(len(name_list)))
end = datetime.now()
delta = end-start
print "Query time = ", delta
```

Comment: Note that the expected size of the list (names of authors) for 65 Mb data file is 320,000. It's basically a performance test.

Comment: +1 thanks for posting the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [lxml benchmarks](http://codespeak.net/lxml/performance.html) are quite useful. It appears to me that extracting element nodes using XPath is fast but extracting text could be slow. Below, I've three solutions that are pretty fast.

```
def bench_lxml_xpath_direct(root): # Very slow but very fast if text() is removed.
  name_list = root.xpath("book/author/name/text()")
  print ("Size of list = " + str(len(name_list)))

def bench_lxml_xpath_loop(root): # Fast
  name_list = root.xpath("book/author/name")
  result = []
  for n in name_list:
    result.append(n.text)

  print ("Size of list = " + str(len(name_list)))

def bench_lxml_getiterator(tree): # Very fast
  result = []
  for name in tree.getiterator("name"):
    result.append(name.text)
  print ("Size of list = " + str(len(result)))


def bench_lxml_findall(tree):  # Superfast
  result = []
  for name in tree.findall("//name"):
    result.append(name.text)
  print ("Size of list = " + str(len(result)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you can rewrite the xpath expression to run faster? One thing that may work is to avoid building the name_list nodeset (if you don't need it later) and have the nodes counted inside of lxml. Something like this:

```
start = datetime.now()
name_list_len = root.xpath("count(/book/author/name/text())")
print ("Size of list = " + str(name_list_len))
end = datetime.now()
```

Otherwise, you may find the [expat parser](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html) faster for extracting the text, but it isn't validating, and is more complex to use (you'll need to write a state machine and a couple of callbacks). If you just need the text, it may be faster to use the [C implementation of the element tree API](http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm). The [lxml benchmarks](http://codespeak.net/lxml/performance.html) make interesting reading and do seem to hint that you could extract the text more quickly with that.

One common xpath performance issue is unnecessary use of '//' at the start of the expression. In this case, making the expression absolute, e.g.:

```
 name_list = root.xpath("/rootelement/book/author/name/text()")
```

can be a lot quicker if the document is structured to allow this. Shouldn't be an issue here though.

Comment: Thinking about it, I don't think my answer is quite right - your xpath expression is already absolute (it doesn't start with '//'). Still, 5 mins seems rather long.